# html forms - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, input, react-router

Hello i using a template for my project but i got error in my label 
 onChange : {this.onChange} and value:{this.state.das} i this is the message :
(property) this: any
':' expected.ts(1005) 
this is my code

```
 <div className="content">
      <Grid fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col md={8}>
            <Card
              title="Add New Profile"
              content={
                <form>
                  <FormInputs
                    ncols={["col-md-5", "col-md-3", "col-md-4"]}
                    properties={[
                      {
                        label: "Company (disabled)",
                        type: "text",
                        bsClass: "form-control",
                        placeholder: "ATOS",
                        defaultValue: "ATOS MAROC.",
                        disabled: true,

                      },
                      {
                        label: "DAS",
                        type: "text",
                        bsClass: "form-control",
                        placeholder: "DAS",
                        id:"das",
                        name:"das", 
                        onChange : {this.onChange},
                        value:{this.state.das}


                      },
                      {
                        label: "Email address",
                        type: "email",
                        bsClass: "form-control",
                        placeholder: "Email",
                        id:"email",
                        name:"email",
                      }
                    ]}
                  />
                  <FormInputs
                    ncols={["col-md-6", "col-md-6"]}
                    properties={[
                      {
                        label: "First name",
                        type: "text",
                        bsClass: "form-control",
                        placeholder: "First name",
                        id:"nom",
                        name:"nom",

                      },
                      {
                        label: "Last name",
                        type: "text",
                        bsClass: "form-control",
                        placeholder: "Last name",
                        id:"prenom",
                        name:"prenom",

                      }
                    ]}
                  />

                  <FormInputs
                    ncols={["col-md-4"]}
                    properties={[
                      {
                        label: "Password",
                        type: "password",
                        bsClass: "form-control",
                        placeholder: "password",
                        id:"password",
                        name:"password",

                      },


                    ]}

                  />
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="inputState">Statu</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="statut" id="statut">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="admin">Administrateur</option>
                    <option value="sales">SalesLead</option>
                  </select>
                </div>


                  <Button bsStyle="info" pullRight fill type="submit">
                   ADD USER
                  </Button>
                  <div className="clearfix" />
                </form>



              }
            />
          </Col>

        </Row>
      </Grid>
```

please what i should to do ? what is the correct syntaxt to write this :   onChange : {this.onChange},
                        value:{this.state.das}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need to drop the braces

```
{
  label: "DAS",
  type: "text",
  bsClass: "form-control",
  placeholder: "DAS",
  id:"das",
  name: "das", 
  onChange : this.onChange,
  value: this.state.das
}
```